# Set mouse wheel to horizontal scroll using css

Tags: html, css, scroll, mouse

I want to design a horizontal page. When I use mouse wheel it just scrolls content vertically. How can I use horizontal scroll by mouse wheel?  Does CSS support this property?

For example any thing like this:

```
mouse-wheel:horizontal;
```

I dont want jQuery solutions.

Comment: CSS not, JS does support it.
jQuery is not necessary.
I've tested Calvins answer below and works great.

Answer (score 63):

We can scroll the page horizontally by SHIFT key + scroll through mouse.

Comment: Doesn't help me in my case, but that's a cool trick. Thanks! :)

Comment: Like @CollinAnderson, its none of my business but a cool trick. My thanks is in the form of upvote. ;)

Answer (score 43):

Rotate the container by –90 degrees, then rotate its child element by 90 degrees.

```css
.container {
  width: 180px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.content {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 10px;

  background-color: #a8a8df;
  
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  <div class="content">Content 5</div>
  <div class="content">Content 6</div>
  <div class="content">Content 7</div>
</div>
```

See [Pieter Biesemans’ article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/) about it; he also lists browser compatibility.

Comment: Try adding some example code to show what you mean.

Comment: I noticed the scroll bar is on top of the div. Swap the rotate value of container and content. The Container is 90deg and Content is -90deg.

Comment: this will cause more problems than it's solved.

Comment: This is pretty hacky, but ingenious. I love it. Probably not best suited for production though :D

Answer (score 24):

CSS does not support manipulation of mouse or keyboard inputs; input controls can only be manipulated via JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to say that it can be done with javascript and you do not need Jquery

Comment: I disagree with "CSS does not support manipulation of mouse". CSS interacts with mouse in many ways such like `pointer-events`, `cursor`, or `:hover`. I personally think CSS should have proper way to direct mouse wheels on element.

Answer (score 20):

```
var item = document.getElementById("MAIN");

  window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) item.scrollLeft += 100;
    else item.scrollLeft -= 100;
  });
```

Where `"MAIN"` is your container

Comment: perfect! I even ID'd html tag to MAIN and worked perfect.
Just one thing, when adding `e.preventDefault();` inside the function, it doesn't makes a difference to avoid conflict of vertical and horizontal scrolling on elements that have the possibility. What could be wrong there?

Comment: Just perfect one !

Comment: Simple and working, thanks!

Comment: It is scrolling up/down and left/right simultaneously - how to prevent scrolling vertically then? As David suggested preventDefault is not working.

Comment: Can even make it shorter: `(event) => event.currentTarget.scrollLeft += event.deltaY`. Don't need getElementById - get if from the event. Don't need the if - deltaY can be +100 / 0 / -100.

Answer (score 9):

There is no style like this in css

```css
div {
  scroll-direction: horizontal;
}
```

That could have been very handy. But YET, **You have a way to do it**
You can also create your own.
**Easy With JavaScript**

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
// where "container" is the id of the container
  container.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      container.scrollLeft += 100;
      e.preventDefault();
// prevenDefault() will help avoid worrisome 
// inclusion of vertical scroll 
    }
    else {
      container.scrollLeft -= 100;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
// That will work perfectly
```

Or if you like to do CSS, this will create the container, rotate it, rotate the items, and scroll.
The steps:

1. Create the `container` item and add css:

```html
<!------ HTML ------>

<div class="container">
 <div>item 1</div>
 <div>item 2</div>
 <div>item 3</div>
 <div>item 4</div>
 <div>item 5</div>
 <div>item 6</div>
 <div>item 7</div>
 <div>item 8</div>
</div>
```

```css
/** CSS **/

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
}

.container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Also to make the mousescroll smooth we can add

container.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft IE 10 has a prefixed property, take a look at -ms-scroll-translation... but just to you know... it is not widely supported yet, but still a good idea :(

Comment: +1. This also works in Edge 13 and IE 11. However, according to the Microsoft docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996917.aspx) the CSS property only works on Windows 8 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Add this into the container: `onWheel= "this.scrollLeft+=event.deltaY>0?100:-100"`

Example:

```
<div class= "container" onWheel= "this.scrollLeft+=event.deltaY>0?100:-100" >
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

CSS does not support manipulation of mouse or keyboard inputs

You could use Jquery.Check the following example

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score -5):

You can't achieve this with only CSS you need to use Jquery for this. Below is example link where the horizontal scroll was achieved by using jquery.

Example link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/