# How can I make a div scroll Horizontally with mouse-wheel in CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want div.ListContainer (it contains 10 nos. of div.FoodCard) to be scrolled with mouse-wheel. I used transform: rotate(180deg); method but it has glitches with other transform properties.
I'm working in react so suggest a method that would work best for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEL6q.png)

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vh 5%;
  text-align: center;
  div.ListContainer {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    div.FoodCard {
      position: relative;
      height: 320px;
      min-width: 280px;
      background: pink;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      &:hover{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      div.FrontFace {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: lightblue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

      }
      div.BackFace {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: lightcoral;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        backface-visibility: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Catch the scroll event and scroll your div manually?

Comment: I know its not nice to hear this now but... from a ux standpoint i would avoid this. It will break well established behavior pattern for the user and lead to confusion. Thats poor ux design.

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481308/set-mouse-wheel-to-horizontal-scroll-using-css

Comment: what are the glitches you experimented ? here an example , using rotate(90deg) and also writing-mode https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rEvyqL (it was meant to show the last element at first)  the only absolute element is a pseudo on html for the background . Can you share a working demonstration of your issue in your snippet?