# CSS: Horizontal scrolling (overflow-x: scroll) Not Working

Tags: html, css

I have 3 "pages" and want to horizontal scroll through them.
I have managed to create an horizontal scroll bar BUT **when I scroll up/down** with my mousewheel nothing happens.

**This is how my container looks:**

```css
body .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}
```

Full HTML + CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

body .container section {
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgb(33, 59, 27);
  color: green;
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgb(45, 42, 39);
  color: rgb(182, 216, 182);
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: rgb(52, 41, 33);
  color: rgb(87, 33, 233);
}

body .container section h1 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10em;
}

body .container section p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!-- main wrapper of the content for the whole webpage -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- sections of the web page -->
  <section>
    <h1>Page1</h1>
    <p>random text</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page2</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page3</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

I tried to Google but didn't find any solution... And I got all this from a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNPkVQD7vlM&t=54s).

Comment: _"I have managed to create an horizontal scroll bar BUT when I scroll up/down with my mousewheel nothing happens."_ This sentence confused me. How the mousewheel (targeted at scrolling vertically) should affect the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: maybe this will answer your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481308/set-mouse-wheel-to-horizontal-scroll-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a bit of javascript here and you have to remove the width and height property from container

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}


body .container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

body .container section {
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgb(33, 59, 27);
  color: green;
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgb(45, 42, 39);
  color: rgb(182, 216, 182);
}

body .container section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: rgb(52, 41, 33);
  color: rgb(87, 33, 233);
}

body .container section h1 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10em;
}

body .container section p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!-- main wrapper of the content for the whole webpage -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- sections of the web page -->
  <section>
    <h1>Page1</h1>
    <p>random text</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page2</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page3</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the JS script to my HTML (script tag within the body) but nothing has changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you use the code I provided? @golfcat

Comment: yes! same css code and html with the script you posted inside the body tag.

Comment: well it runs here...better to recheck your code