# horizontally scrolling div won't scroll using mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a horizontally scrolling div that is easy to navigate via mac's trackpad, but a nightmare to navigate using a mouse. The user has to actually click and drag via the scrollbar at the bottom of the page in order to scroll through the content.

I have tried implementing numerous solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481308/set-mouse-wheel-to-horizontal-scroll-using-css) post to my code, but have yet to get any of them working.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/730ox21s/1/) is a link to a jsfiddle using one of the javascript solutions. Easy to scroll horizontally with the trackpad, but still unable to scroll horizontally using mousewheel.

I need to ensure that the solution doesn't ruin the trackpad scrolling experience either, but simply makes it possible to also scroll using the mousewheel. For example, I see that if the user just holds the shift button, they can scroll perfectly normal with the mousewheel OR the trackpad. Maybe a workaround is just writing some code that forces the shift key to be pressed the entire time the user is on the page? Sounds like a dumb workaround lol. Would rather just use javascript that works.

Here is the code I'm attempting to use -

```
<script>
  
 const container = document.getElementById("horizontalstorecontainer");
// where "container" is the id of the container
  container.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      container.scrollLeft += 100;
      e.preventDefault();
// prevenDefault() will help avoid worrisome 
// inclusion of vertical scroll 
    }
    else {
      container.scrollLeft -= 100;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
// That will work perfectly 

  </script>
```

Please note I removed images and such to simplify as they are not at all related to this question. And I'm not looking for a CSS solution. Thank you!

EDIT: something else to note, the user will never be scrolling vertically on any of the webpages. Maybe this makes the solution even easier?

EDIT2: [This](https://ibb.co/3Bw1SRp) image shows the error I get when trying the code in the suggested answer on this post... my content still only scrolls horizontally with a vertical mousewheel when I hold down the shift key...

Comment: How are you going to convince users that they can use the mouse wheel to scroll horizontally? How? How?

Comment: Currently the only way users can scroll with a mouse is by actually using the scrollbar. I simply need the mouse wheel to work so users have other easier options. There’s an animation on page load that quickly scrolls thru all the products so you can see the div is scrollable. Not asking for UX help just need the mouse wheel to work :)

Comment: @SalmanA If it can't scroll vertically but can horizontally, I would expect mouse scroll (without `Shift`) to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made few correction on your code you provide in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/730ox21s/1/).

- Your script to scroll the content is before `<body>` and you have `document.getElementById("horizontalstorecontainer");` in that script. It will not find your `div` with id `"horizontalstorecontainer"`, because your js is loaded before DOM load.
- Similarly, you are doing `container.scrollLeft += 100;`. Here,container is a div with `horizontalstorecontainer`. Which does not have scrollbar, the scroll bar is in `<div class="store-scrolling-wrapper">`. So, the [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) doesnot work. See following image.
  [image]

So, I did following changes to make your code working.

1. `const itemToScroll = document.getElementById("itemToScroll");` stored div that has scrollbar to a itemToScroll. Note: I have added id to `<div id="itemToScroll" class="store-scrolling-wrapper">`
2. `if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 0)` checked `deltaY` value is greater than 0 or not. If it is grater than 0 then it is vertical scroll. Why [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) because scroll up will return negative `deltaY`.
3. `e.preventDefault();` if it is vertical scroll. So that it will disable the default behaivour and we can override it with horizontal scroll.

<sup>*<sub>Note: Add your JavaScript to scroll at the button of page.</sub></sup>

```js
const container = document.getElementById("horizontalstorecontainer");
const itemToScroll = document.getElementById("itemToScroll");

container.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    itemToScroll.scrollLeft +=e.deltaY;
    
    // itemToScroll.scrollTo({
    //  left: itemToScroll.scrollLeft + e.deltaY,
    // });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black !important;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1vh;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.front {
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.back {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: love 5s infinite;
  animation: love 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

#horizontalstorecontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.clothingcardfirst {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-right: 32.5%;
}

.clothingcard1 img,
.clothingcard2 img,
.cardlast img,
.cardlast2022 img,
.cardlast2021 img,
.cardlast2020 img,
.clothingcardlast img,
.clothingcardfirst img {
  height: 100%;
}

.animationwrapperclothing {
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.store-scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.store-scrolling-wrapper-clothing {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.cardlast {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation-name: storeslide;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: storeslide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-name: storeslide;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-name: storeslide;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -o-animation-delay: .3s;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.productwrapperclothing {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

.cardlast img {
  height: 100%;
}

.animationwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2400px;
  -moz-perspective: 2400px;
  -ms-perspective: 2400px;
  -o-perspective: 2400px;
  perspective: 2400px;
}

.animationwrapperless {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 3000px;
  -moz-perspective: 3000px;
  -ms-perspective: 3000px;
  -o-perspective: 3000px;
  perspective: 3000px;
}

.anotherwrapperlol {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
}

@keyframes storeslide {
  0% {
    margin-left: -535%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 32.5%;
  }
}

.animationwrapperclothing {
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.animationwrapperclothing>a {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.productwrapper {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

.productwrapperclothing {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

.productwrapperclothing {
  padding: 0;
}

.animationwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2400px;
  -moz-perspective: 2400px;
  -ms-perspective: 2400px;
  -o-perspective: 2400px;
  perspective: 2400px;
}

.itemandpricewrapper,
.itemandpricewrapperclothing {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 42px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.animationwrapperless {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 3000px;
  -moz-perspective: 3000px;
  -ms-perspective: 3000px;
  -o-perspective: 3000px;
  perspective: 3000px;
}

.clothing {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.clothingcard2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.clothingcard1 img,
.clothingcard2 img,
.cardlast img,
.cardlast2022 img,
.cardlast2021 img,
.cardlast2020 img,
.clothingcardlast img,
.clothingcardfirst img {
  height: 100%;
}

.itemandpricewrapper>a,
.itemandpricewrapperclothing>a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-text, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-text, sans-serif;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

#collagebutton,
#inkbutton,
#crossbutton,
#crossbutton2,
#streakbutton,
#thermalbutton,
#databendbutton,
#trilogybutton,
#temperaturebutton,
#crosscollectorsbutton,
#streakcollectorsbutton,
#temperaturecollectorsbutton,
#phaserblackbutton,
#phaserwhitebutton,
#embroideredlogohoodieblackbutton,
#atrbutton,
#atrvhsbutton,
#articlebutton,
#lolbutton,
#lollbutton,
#lolllbutton,
#gesturemorn,
#roonhood,
#smallpaint,
#bigpaint,
#thegesturebutton,
#mediumpaint,
#d8,
#bb,
#brb,
#sb,
#charhood,
#fghood,
#whood,
#rbhood,
#ana,
#whydontyouwork,
#pig,
#met,
#mett,
#unc,
#cs,
#cs2,
#cs3,
#cs4,
#cs5,
#cs6,
#cs7,
#cs8,
#cs9,
#cs10,
#cs11,
#cs12,
#cs13,
#cs14,
#cs15,
#philly1,
#philly2,
#philly3,
#holy,
#holyu,
#font,
#cwb,
#cw,
#cwu,
#gjh,
#bf1,
#bf2,
#bf3 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.deckcard2,
.deckcard3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.deckcard1 img,
.storecard img,
.deckcard2 img,
.deckcard3 img,
.deckcard0 img {
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .cardlast {
    animation-name: storeslidemobile;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: .3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: storeslidemobile;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-name: storeslidemobile;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-name: storeslidemobile;
    -o-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: .3s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
  .productwrapperclothing {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.typekit.net/lzh8cbl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="horizontalstorecontainer">
  <div id="itemToScroll" class="store-scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="cardlast">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapper">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cw">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapperless">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cwu">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapper">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="font">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapperless">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TESTT</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="holyu">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapper">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cs3">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapperless">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cs4">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clothingcard2">
      <div class="productwrapperclothing">
        <div class="animationwrapperclothing">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="images/" alt="." class="clothing" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapperclothing">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="streakbutton">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deckcard3">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/" class="animationwrapperless">
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="images/" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cs5">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clothingcard2">
      <div class="productwrapperclothing">
        <div class="animationwrapperclothing">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="images/" alt="." class="clothing" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="philly2">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clothingcard2">
      <div class="productwrapperclothing">
        <div class="animationwrapperclothing">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="images/" alt="." class="clothing" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="philly3">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clothingcardfirst">
      <div class="productwrapperclothing">
        <div class="animationwrapperclothing">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="images/" alt="." class="clothing" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="itemandpricewrapper">
          <a href="/">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
          </a>
          <h2>$ ??.??</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cs">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx8gc2nk/3/).

Comment: You made my entire week. I am so happy! Thank you so much for the detailed answer. This works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. This is going to make our site a lot easier to navigate.

Comment: It appears I'm no longer able to 'zoom in' with a track pad when using this new code... is this just something that comes along with changing the vertical scroll, or is it still somehow possible to zoom in while using this code? @kiran

Comment: @JohnSmith I think you need to make little twist in the condition. if(Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 0 && e.deltaX === 0)

Comment: thank you so much! I’m excited to try this. Do you know where within the script I should add this line?

Comment: @JohnSmith replace `if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 0) {` to `if(Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 0 && e.deltaX === 0) `

Comment: Thank you so much @Kiran I have created an updated JSFiddle by replacing that line with the new line, but I still can't seem to be able to zoom into the container with a trackpad. Here is the updated JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q248a5fb/ Do you know what I have done wrong?

Comment: @JohnSmith https://jsfiddle.net/2b1mw3sj/ try this one

Comment: thank you for sending this JSFiddle. Unfortunately I still can't seem to zoom with the trackpad. Is there any way where the script is only applied to users that have a mouse, but it doesn't apply when the user uses a trackpad?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mac or a trackpad so you have to test these theories but your code works with mousewheel, so only problem left is trackpad issue. Probably `e.preventDefault();` prevents trackpad to scroll horizontally.

- Solution 1: If your trackpad already fires horizontal scroll events, try not preventing the event if `e.deltaX` has a value (different than 0).

```js
    if (e.deltaX == 0) { 
    //this scroll is not horizontal
    //still prevent it and manually adjust scrollLeft
      if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        container.scrollLeft += 100;
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        container.scrollLeft -= 100;
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    //else let the horizontal scroll work
```

- Solution 2: If solution 1 is not what you want, then try deleting `e.preventDefault();` lines completely. You already said users will not be scrolling vertically at all, so we actually don't need this line. If you want to make sure there will be no vertical surprises, we can try to prevent this on the html meta tags by adding

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height"/>`
</head>
```

optionally you can prevent zoom:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`
</head>
```

and we can set some style for the body element just to make sure:

```html
<body style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 100vh;">
 some page content
</body>
```

this should be enough to prevent vertical scrolling without preventing it in the javascript.

EDIT:
Regarding to your comment, yes your code works for me. Guessing that you only have one `horizontalstorecontainer` per page, you can add the event listener to the `document` rather than `container` for better results:

```js
 const container = document.getElementById("horizontalstorecontainer");
// where "container" is the id of the container
  document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) { //edit this line <--
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      container.scrollLeft += 100;
      e.preventDefault();
// prevenDefault() will help avoid worrisome 
// inclusion of vertical scroll 
    }
    else {
      container.scrollLeft -= 100;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }, {passive: false}); //try this if you are getting my error below
```

I was getting an error `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event...` and adding `{passive: false}` solved my issue but i'm not sure if this is related to your problem or if this can break some other event/codes you might have.

This is working for me on a container that has `overflow-x: scroll;`. When i run this code the webpage stops scrolling and only my container scrolls horizontally with my scrollwheel. Tried this on chrome.

Maybe you can debug this event by adding `console.log(e);` to the beginning of function to see if the event is firing for your mousewheel and you can also see if you are getting the `deltaY` values you want. If the event is firing perfectly, examine container to see why it's not moving.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in the original JSFiddle the mousewheel does not scroll the container horizontally for me. The trackpad is no issue and works perfect to scroll. But I cannot get the mousewheel to work. Can you confirm the mousewheel somehow is working for you? If it is, do you know why it wouldn't be working for me? I am confident my mousewheel isn't broken as it works fine with other sites. Only when I hold down the shift key does the mousewheel work for me in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Edited my answer for details. Also if available, maybe try your code on different browser and computers to see if it is related to a mac issue.

Comment: Thank you! I have tested this on a macbook with a mouse, and on a PC desktop with a mouse, and have not been able to get the original JSFiddle or the proposed answer to work with the mousewheel unfortunately. Both only worked when I held down the shift key.

Comment: I have updated the post with an image showing the error I get, even when using the passive false route